# Obj-C, Navigation Controller with Tab Controller am I using them incorrectly?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

When I first setup my app I had some issues getting a single navigation controller to work.

I have several screens behind each tab item. I think the problem I was getting was that view controllers would show within the wrong tabs, when switching between them. I'm not bothered about keeping the last view controller used open within each tab, in fact I hide the tab bar to stop this anway now.

So at the moment I have navigation controller files for each of my tabs. I have them assigned in IB, in the mainWindow.

And I use them like this...

```
CategorySelTableViewController *nextController = 
          [[[CategorySelTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:
          @"CategorySelTableView" bundle:nil] autorelease];
nextController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;

MyAppDelegate *delegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
         delegate];

[delegate.billsndepsNavController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
```

However, I have some leaks.

I can't release my delegate, it causes an error.

My colleuge suggests that I should just be using `self.navigationcontroller`.

But this is a big change for me, I'd like to know definetively if I'm doing this wrong before I make the changes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a view controller is pushed into the stack, it has two ways to access the navigation controller:

- Using `self.navigationController`.
- Accessing the navigation controller ivar in the delegate:
  `[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.navigationController`

Both are equivalent but the first one is shorter, so it tends to be used more. There is no benefit from switching from one to the other. The only reason to do the extra typing is when you are not in a *pushed* view controller, eg: a view controller used in an independent GUI component, or an object that is not a view controller.

The delegate shouldn't be released because it exists during the whole life of the application.

Comment: I'm saying I do have a nav controller for each tab. I'm confused. So don't use a delegate, like I am in the code above ? Can you provide some further code, which I would use instead ?

Comment: Anyone, this answer seems confusing from my question ?

Comment: So your saying use one navigation controller for me whole app ?

Comment: If your app has independent sections you should use a tab bar controller. If you use tabs you should use one navigation controller per tab (already provided in the Xcode template project. To reference a nav controller while using tabs just use self.navigationController. You can't use tabs and use only one nav controller.