# iOS4 - custom uiview accessing UINavigation stack

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiviewcontroller, navigation

Bit confused with this one so bear with me...

I have a Navigation-based project which is working fine.  I'm trying to create my first custom UIView to make a couple of buttons which I will use in multiple places.  One of the buttons needs to push a viewcontroller into the navigation when it's clicked but I'm not sure how to do this.

When I had the button set up within a view controller I was using:

```
LocationViewController *controller = [[LocationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LocationViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
        [controller release];
```

but the self.navigation controller won't work now, will it?  How do I access the navigation controller of the viewcontroller that this uiview will be added to?

Hope at least some of that makes sense, as I said it's my first go at subclassing the uiview and adding it to multiple pages so I'm a bit lost.

EDIT TO ADD - I have the button click events inside the custom UIView, so that is where I'm trying to change the viewcontroller from.  Should I instead wire up the events in whichever viewcontroller I add the view to?

Comment: does your App has only one navigation controller or multiple .

Comment: app only has one navigation controller set up in the delegate right at the start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually your appDelegate has a UINavigationController property. You can access it in your custom view like this:

```
UINavigationController *navController = (MyAppDelegate *)[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
         delegate] navigationController];
```

But more effective way is to make delegate method for your custom view and handle button action in your viewController.

```
MyCustomView.h

    @protocol MyCustomViewDelegate 
    @interface MyCustomView : UIView  {
        id<MyCustomViewDelegate>    cvDelegate; }
    @property(nonatomic, assign) id<MyCustomViewDelegate>   cvDelegate;

    @protocol MyCustomViewDelegate @optional
    -(void)didClickInCustomView:(MyCustomViewDelegate*)view withData:(NSObject*)data; 
    @end
```

MyCustomView.m

```
    - (void)myButtonClick:(id)sender 
    { 
        [self.cvDelegate didClickInCustomView:self withData:someData];  
    }
```

So now you can handle this event in any place where is your custom
view.

Comment: That worked, with a minor coding change, seems to need extra square bracket before the (MyAppDelegate *) and closing one at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Add the button from the interface builder or from the view controller's viewDidLoad using code:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24);
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(handleMyButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Then implement `-(void)handleMyButton:(id)sender {};` in your view controller. Or you could instead write `-(IBAction)handleMyButton:(id)sender {};` and link method and button using the interface builder.

Then inside the method just paste the block of code you posted above. If you started with the Xcode navigation controller template project it should work.

I think it's cleaner to [hide the designated initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091697/obj-c-navigation-controller-with-tab-controller-am-i-using-them-incorrectly/8093339#8093339) initWithNibName: because it is an implementation detail.

When you say you are subclassing the UIView I don't know exactly what you mean. If you want to add another view controller with a custom view just use the UIViewController template and customize the XIB file, no need to subclass an UIView unless you are really modifying its behaviour, which I guess you are not. The view is a view, and the controller stuff like handling buttons should be in the controller.

Comment: The row of buttons need to go into almost every viewcontroller though, so I don't want to have to repeat the same code - I'm trying to make a re-usable view that I can just drop in and have work in every section.

Answer (score 0):

The actual controller need to be in the navigation controller stack to be able to push another controller.

Or you can make a new navigation controller instance and push your LocationViewController.